# Purpose of Backbone's Router?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

What is the purpose of Backbone's Router? Can't we do the same thing without it? With a router, a click on a link would change the URL of a page and the last bits of the URL would trigger a function. Why not just assign a click event on this link and trigger a function there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use backbone specifically, (rather, I use iron-router for my project) but it's purpose is to route URLs to pages. Consider the following: you have 50 links scattered across your website's source all pointing to /awesomePlace (which serves awesomePlace.html). You've decided awesomePlace isn't so awesome anymore and have declared that there is a moreAwesomePlace.html. You could go in and change each of those 50 links to /moreAwesomePlace or you could change the route once. The router could then serve up moreAwesomePlace.html whenever anybody visits /awesomePlace.

That's just one example. I personally haven't spent too much time with routers yet but I'm sure somebody can give some better examples than I have. Hopefully this helps explain things a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can implement same functionalities without router, router is just an helper utility, just like JQuery for DOM manipulations. Reason behind using router all about scalability and flexibility. If you follow "on click do some thing", it does't scale. In a single page application every click might have multiple handlers. One click on item might demand changes to multiple widgets. with routers you can add/remove hooks for the same click. And in future if you want to change the implementation of Router or hooks, you are free to do that, only thing that you need to make sure is contract btw these two remain same.